# Kivy: Расположение text в label

Tags: kivy

Я пытаюсь расположить `text` у левого верхнего края в виджете `label`.

Пробовал использовать параметр `Window.width - dp(...), None`, но получилась вообще белиберда какая то, так же пробовал использовать параметр `self.size` - на нём я сейчас и становился.

kv:

```
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        font_size: 25
        size_hint: 1, 0.7
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "top": 1} 
        text:'GAME'
                
        text_size: self.size
```

p.s. Синим выделен сам виджет label.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: valign 
Vertical alignment of the text.
valign is an OptionProperty and defaults to ‘bottom’. Available options are : ‘bottom’, ‘middle’ (or ‘center’) and ‘top’.  https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.valign

Comment: @Интик , теперь всё как надо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь `halign: 'center'` - Выравнивание по центру. Может получиться